# Question about cyclic (Renew Question)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

At my [Finding the "square root" of a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581258/question-about-permutation-i-add-new-details-now-it-shold-be-more-clear)([Finding the "square root" of a permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581258/question-about-permutation-i-add-new-details-now-it-shold-be-more-clear)

I explain it wrong , now I try to explain it better (I edit the old Q to).

=========================================================

$r$ is odd, and $ord(\alpha)=r$. ($\alpha,\beta$ are cycles ).

Now, $\alpha=(a_1\cdots a_n)$.
I need to find $\beta$ That will make $$\alpha = \beta^2$$

How can I show it?

What I tried:

$ord(\alpha)=r$ so $a^{r+1}=\alpha$.

Let say that $\beta=\alpha^{\frac{r+1}{2}}$, $\frac{r+1}{2}$ is an integer, how do I prove that $\alpha^\frac{r+1}{2}$ is cyclic?

Because then $\alpha=\beta^2$....

This is where I stuck...

Thank you and sorry for the another Q, but now thing are more clear...

Comment: I hope I did it right...
(I tried to understand why no one answer...)

Comment: I don't understand the answer...
How he got it?

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang - We didn't leran the lemma that you use so I need a proof without this lemma...:)
Thank you!

Comment: No... But if I understand I don't know if I can use it....

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang - There is another way to solve it? without the lemma...

Comment: I understand the lemma but I can use it :-(. We didn't learn it on the clas...

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang - You right, but it's exercise that I should solve...
And I can use only what we learn at the class...

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang, Yes, but I didn't understand it...
I think it should be more simple...

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang - Yes! :-) But I didn't understand how this helps me here...

Comment: @DeiborlangNongsiang - Can you help me please to find a simpler solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We have $\alpha(a_i)=a_{i+1}$ for $i<n$ and $\alpha(a_n)=a_1$. So we have the relation $a_1\rightarrow a_2 \rightarrow \dots a_{n-1} \rightarrow a_n \rightarrow a_1$. Did you see that we start with $a_1$ and end with $a_1$. To show that $\beta$ is a cycle, we should have such a relation. Now $\beta(a_1)=a_{m+1}$, where $m=\frac{n+1}{2}$,  $\beta(a_2)=a_{m+2}$, $\beta(a_3)=a_{m+3} \dots \beta(a_m)=a_{1}$. In general $\beta(a_i)=a_{m+i}$ if $i<m$ and $\beta(a_i)=a_{i-m+1}$ if $n\geq i\geq m$. So we get the following relation

$a_1\rightarrow a_{m+1} \rightarrow a_2 \rightarrow a_{m+2} \dots a_{n} \rightarrow a_m \rightarrow a_1$

(Note that $n=2m-1$.) Which is a cycle.

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't understand something: if $\beta=(123456789)$, $\beta^3$ it's not cycle, but I'f I'm see it right, by your answer it's cycle...
(I hope I was clear).

Comment: With this $\beta$, you should take $\beta^5$, not $\beta^3$. Note that we have take $m=\frac{n+1}{2}$, so in this case $n=9$ and so $m=5$ and not 3.

Comment: I still left some gap here. If you can't fill in those gap, then inform me. I will see it tomorrow.

Comment: If you can do this before tomorrow it will be great!