# Square root of permutation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have been thinking about square roots of permutations. I realized that the square of cycle of odd length is a cycle with the same length and the square of cycle with even length is multiplication of two cycles of half length.

Can the number of roots of some permutation be found in explicit way? What other facts about these roots are known?

Comment: Note that $(1,2,3)^2=((1,2,3)(a,b))^2$ for all $a, b\not\in\{1, 2, 3\}$, so for large $n$, the number of roots can become quite large...

Comment: Notice that $x^2$ must be element of $A_n$,thus if $y\in (S_n-A_n)\implies$
$x^2=y$ has no solution.

Comment: [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=square+roots+in+permutation+groups) turns up many interesting and relevant-seeming leads, including this [relevant MO thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41784/roots-of-permutations)

Comment: Also [Finding the “square root” of a permutation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581258/finding-the-square-root-of-a-permutation)

Answer (score -1):

You can find a general formula in the following reference: Jesús Leanos, Rutilo Moreno, and Luis Manuel Rivera-Martınez."On the number of mth roots of permutations." AUSTRALASIAN JOURNAL OF COMBINATORICS 52 (2012): 41-54.