# Finding a permutation from a power of itself

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Find a permutation $\sigma \in S_9$ such that $\sigma^2=(13579)(268).$

---

So I know that $\sigma^{10}=\sigma.$ But I don't know $\sigma^5$..... Is $\sigma^{10}=\sigma^4\sigma^6$? I doubt this is the case because I am not getting the correct answer.

Comment: You don't have $\sigma^{10} = \sigma$ for that permutation. $9$ is not an exponent of $S_9$. What is the order of the product of two disjoint cycles?

Comment: Why don't I have a $\sigma^{10}=\sigma$? Isn't $\sigma^9=\epsilon$, with $\epsilon$ being the identity. Is the order 15?

Comment: Because $lcm(3,5)=15$, you have $\sigma^{30}=\epsilon$.

Comment: In this case, the order is indeed $5\cdot 3 = 15$.

Comment: @vadim: You mean $\sigma^{15}=\epsilon$, right? (Not that what you said is wrong...)

Comment: No, $(\sigma^2)^{15}=\epsilon$.  While it's true that also $\sigma^{15}=\epsilon$, that is not immediate.  For example, if you were in $S_{11}$, it would not be true necessarily.

Comment: Also how do I find $\sigma^{30}$ if I have none of the odd powers of $\sigma$?

Comment: I can't find $\sigma^{15}$...

Comment: @allie You need $\sigma^{16} = \sigma$, so $(\sigma^2)^8$.

Comment: Ah you're right. Thank you

Comment: You might find this useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581258/finding-the-square-root-of-a-permutation

Answer (score 1):

A "square root" of $(13579)$ is $(17395)$. A "square root" of $(268)$ is $(286)$.

Comment: How did you figure that?

Comment: Well, it just sort of came to me in a flash. But you can see that it works, right? In fact, any odd-length cycle $(s_1s_2\ldots s_{2n-1})$ has the square root $(s_1s_{n+1}s_2s_{n+2}\ldots s_{2n-2}s_{n-1}s_{2n-1}s_n)$.